# Reporting Services and Crystal Reports Difference

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services

I have a report on RS and another Report on CR.
The Queries are the same, both need parameters so that the report can show the information.

When I run the Query on MSSQL Server There is no difference in the data but when I try to run my report (RS) On Visual Studio 2008 the data is different.

For example:
Order by: Street 
On the database I have 2 rows with empty streets so those will be the 1st one to show, but RS is showing me one and CR is showing me both of them.

I can't put the whole query as it is Huge so if you need more information I'll try to do my best and put it here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I found that the group properties was arranging by a column and that is why show only one.